# SQL query with Ruby output from multiple tables?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm working on a WK poule system and am at the point where I have to find the predicted winners in the fourth round for the quarters.

The user makes a `Prediction` (in a `pool`, through `Poolmembership`).
In the fourth round it worked like this:

knockoutprediction.html.erb view.

```
  <% games.each_with_index do |game, index2| %>
<% current_poolmembership = Poolmembership.find_by_user_id_and_pool_id(current_user.id, @pool.id) %>
<% prediction = Prediction.find_by_poolmembership_id_and_game_id(current_poolmembership, game.id) %>
<% team1 = @array[index2][:team1] %>
<% team2 = @array[index2][:team2] %>

<% team1 = Team.pouleleader(team1[:pos], team1[:poule]) %>
<% team2 = Team.pouleleader(team2[:pos], team2[:poule]) %>

<%= fields_for "predictions[#{index}#{index2}]", Prediction.new do |p| %>
  <%= p.hidden_field :poolmembership_id, :value => Poolmembership.find_by_user_id_and_pool_id(current_user.id, @pool.id).id %>
  <%= p.hidden_field :game_id, :value => game.id %>
  <%= p.hidden_field :team1_id, :value => game.team1_id %>
  <%= p.hidden_field :team2_id, :value => game.team2_id %>
  <tr>
```

and I could use them in code like this:

```
<%= team1[0]['name'] %> - <%= team2[0]['name'] %>
```

knockoutpredictionscontroller.rb, before action :fourth round

```
def fourthround
  @array = [
    {
      team1: {
        pos: 1,
        poule: 'A'
      },
      team2: {
        pos: 2,
        poule: 'B'
      }
    },
    {
      team1: {
        pos: 2,
        poule: 'A'
      },
      team2: {
        pos: 1,
        poule: 'B'
      }
    } 
  ] 
end
```

And it was driven by this, Team.rb model:

```
def self.pouleleader(position, poule)
  Team.connection.execute """
    SELECT tp.pouleposition, t.poule, t.name, t.id
    FROM teampredictions tp
      LEFT JOIN teams t
        ON tp.team_id = t.id
    WHERE tp.pouleposition = #{position}
    AND t.poule = '#{poule}'
  """
end
```

Now I'm at the point where I need the predicted teams in knockout predictions to set up a new prediction for the quarters, with the teams. My idea was to save the winner of an knockout prediction into the predictionstable (which saves every prediction), and this works. But, I don't know how to pick it in the next round.

My idea was something like this, Game.rb:

```
def self.eightleader(final, poule, position)
  Team.connection.execute """
    SELECT p.final, t.poule, t.name, t.id, tp.pouleposition
    FROM predictions p
      LEFT JOIN teams t
        ON p.winner = t.id
      LEFT JOIN teampredictions tp
        ON tp.team_id = t.id
    WHERE p.final = '#{final}'
    AND t.poule = '#{poule}'
    AND tp.pouleposition = #{position}      
  """
end
```

view:

```
<% team2 = Team.eightleader(team2[:final], team2[:poule], team2[:pos]) %>
```

Controller:

```
def eightleader
  @array = [
    {
      team1: {
        final: 4,  
        poule: 'A',                  
        pos: 1
      },
      team2: {
        final: 4,           
        poule: 'B',                   
        pos: 2
      },
      team1: {
        final: 4,  
        poule: 'A',                  
        pos: 2
      },
      team2: {
        final: 4,           
        poule: 'B',                   
        pos: 1
      }        
    }
  ] 
end
```

Final is sent too, when the knockout prediction was made, I thought it was useful for finding the right finals (1/4, 1/2, 1).

But all I get now is:

```
undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
```

On the

```
<%= team1[0]['name'] %> - <%= team2[0]['name'] %> <br />
```

in quarter predictions (knockout works excellent).
Any ideas how to solve and improve this system for finding the teams for predictions in the next round?

Comment: What does `team1` and `team2` give as result when you debug it?

Comment: I've solved it already by finding winner like p.winner in the view. It wasn't necessary to have it already loaded on this point. Thanks anyway.